# Martingale property for symmetric random work

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, martingales, random-walk

Consider a symmetric random walk of IID $X_i$ where $X_i = \pm 1$ and $Pr(\pm 1) = 0.5$. Define $S_n = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$, therefore $E[S_n] = 0$.

In the notes that I am looking at, it shows the following:

[image]

The way $S_{n+1}$ seems to be weird, and I am not sure if it is a typo. Shouldn't the 2 cases for $S_{n+1}$ be lower case $s_n \pm 1$ instead of upper case $S_n \pm 1$. Upper case is a random variable and lower case is a specific realization, I believe.

If this is correct, then should't the expectation $E[S_{n+1}^2 - (n+1)]$ be equal to $s_n^2 - n$ instead of $S_n^2 - n$?

Comment: 1) No. 2) $E[S_{n+1}^2-(n+1)]=\ldots$ should be $E[S_n^2-(n+1)\mid S_n,\cdots,S_1]=\ldots$.

Comment: Can you expand on (1)? Are you saying that $S_{n+1} = S_n + 1$ with probability 0.5 and $S_{n+1} = S_n - 1$ with proability 0.5? $S_n + 1$ is a random variable, so I don't understand this. 

Where did you get your expression for 2)?

Comment: Formally, $S_{n+1}=S_n+X_{n+1}$, where $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\{S_n,\ldots S_1\}$. Therefore, $\mathsf{E}[S_{n+1}\mid S_n,\ldots,S_1]=\mathsf{E}[S_n+X_{n+1}\mid S_n,\ldots,S_1]=S_n+\mathsf{E}[X_{n+1}]=S_n.$

Comment: @d.k.o. Wait, is the quantity $E[S_{n+1} | S_n, \ldots, S_1]$ a random variable?

Comment: Yes, it is a random variable (as a conditional expectation).

Answer (score 1):

The only typo here is that $E[S2n+1−(n+1)]$ should instead be $E[S2n+1−(n+1)\mid S_1,\ldots, S_n]$. Remember that the conditional expectation $E[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable that is a function of $Y$.